# Laravel: How to use dynamic database using DB facade?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, multi-tenant, laravel-query-builder

Using Laravel 5, how can I access a database dynamically set in the config?

Sample output below is not using the database `some_db` as expected.

```
var_dump(config('database.connections.tenant.database')); // -> 'another_db'
config()->set('database.connections.tenant.database', 'some_db');
var_dump(config('database.connections.tenant.database')); // -> 'some_db'
var_dump(DB::connection('tenant')->select('select database()')); // -> 'another_db'
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what Laravel 5 version you're using, these are the recommended methods of setting config values at runtime. Worth a shot. :)

```
// 5.0
Config::set('key', 'value');

// 5.1 & 5.2
config(['key' => 'value']);
```